# Add scroll to left side navbar and bottom right child content by using flex?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing an angular app with fixed top title, left nav menu and right content. I'm trying to create a layout by using flex, with no success. This is the starting HTML:

```css
.layout-container__header {
    padding-top: 0.8rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.8rem;
    color: white;
    background: #3f51b5;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.layout-container__content__navmenu {
    flex: 1;
}

.layout-container__content__navmenu-header .k-icon {
    margin-top: 0.8rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-left: 0.7rem;
}

#navbar-toggler:hover {
    background-color: #3848a3;
}

.navbar-toggler span {
    align-content: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: var(--palette-color-primary-100);
}

.navbar-toggler span:hover {
    color: white;
}

.header-brand {
    color: white;
}

.header-brand span {
    padding-top: 0.1rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.layout-container__content {
    // margin-top: 4rem;
}

.layout-container__content__body {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-container d-flex flex-column h-100 w-100">
    <div class="layout-container__header d-flex align-self-stretch">
        <div>
            <button id="navbar-toggler" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="k-icon k-i-menu"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="header-brand">
            <span>GeneXsys</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-container__content d-flex flex-grow-1">
        <div class="layout-container__content__main d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-self-stretch">
            <div class="layout-container__content__navmenu">
                <div class="layout-container__content__navmenu-header">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <!-- <span class="k-icon k-i-file-config"></span> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="layout-container__content__navmenu-body">
                    <p>Menu Option 1</p>
                    <p>Menu Option 2</p>
                    <p>Menu Option 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="layout-container__content__body h-100 d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1">
                <p>Content 1</p>
                <p>Content 2</p>
                <p>Content 3</p>
                <p>Content 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set different flex configurations with row/column directions but no success. This is the intented layout taking into account that left panel (side nav menu) should be collapsible and items displayed could overflow the div causing the vertical scrollbars be displayed:

[image]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mockup, that matches yours. I used your class names(with a little adjustments).

Take note of the `.collapse` class, toggle it on/off onto the `.__sidebar` element using javascript

```js
var toggler = document.querySelector("#collapse-sidebar");
var sidebar = document.querySelector(".layout__container__content__sidebar");

toggler.addEventListener("click", function(){
  sidebar.classList.toggle("collapse")
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.layout__container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.layout__container__header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: #3f51b5;
}

.layout__container__content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
}

.layout__container__content__sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.layout__container__content__sidebar.collapse {
  left: -200px;
}

.layout__container__content__body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: peachpuff;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout__container">
        <div class="layout__container__header">
        <button id="collapse-sidebar">Collapse Sidebar</button>
    </div>

        <div class="layout__container__content">
            <div class="layout__container__content__sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                    <li>Item 5</li>
                    <li>Item 6</li>
          <li>Item 7</li>
          <li>Item 8</li>
          <li>Item 9</li>
          <li>Item 10</li>
          <li>More</li>
          <li>More</li>
          <li>More</li>
          <li>More</li>
          <li>More</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      
            <div class="layout__container__content__body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, quia dolorem iure error perferendis, qui rem quae aliquid nostrum odio reiciendis magni, nam maxime fugiat inventore. Natus perspiciatis quo veritatis.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Redemption Okoro, thanks, however the right content is showing a full vertical scrollbars, scrolling the header and content, but I need to scroll only content div, keeping the header fixed, according to the picture.

Comment: Redemption Okoro, on the other hand, I had to use display: flex for layout__container__header and layout__container__content since div inherits display: block causing the child divs do a wrap for the divs next to them towards down

Comment: In reply to your first comment, the code i gave you archives what you mentioned, even in the snippet